# emacs elscreen: want to open multiple shell windows, but the tabs always show the same window

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs with elscreen, and I want to open 2 tabs, each has an eshell instance, but after I used M-x eshell in 2 tabs, both of the tabs show the same content. Is it able to show different eshell instance? or even different shell instance, if it's not possible for eshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `C-u` prefix to get another `eshell` session: `C-u M-x eshell`.

Here's the docstring for `eshell` for more details:

> eshell is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `eshell.el`.
>
> `(eshell &optional ARG)`
>
> Create an interactive Eshell buffer.
>   The buffer used for Eshell sessions is determined by the value of
>   `eshell-buffer-name`.  If there is already an Eshell session active in
>   that buffer, Emacs will simply switch to it.  Otherwise, a new session
>   will begin.  A numeric prefix arg (as in `C-u 42 M-x eshell RET`)
>   switches to the session with that number, creating it if necessary.  A
>   nonnumeric prefix arg means to create a new session.  Returns the
>   buffer selected (or created).